# Laravel 5.2 pagination: how to decrease distance from table

Tags: laravel, twitter-bootstrap-3, laravel-5, laravel-pagination

I have a Laravel 5.2 application. I'm using the default Laravel pagination. All works functionally but there is quite some empty space between the last row of the table and the pagination link. See picture for an example: 
[image]

How can I make the empty space a bit less?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-list">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th class="hidden-xs">Auction id</th>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Description</th>
         <th><em class="fa fa-cog"></em>Actions</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
       @foreach( $events as $event )
       <tr>
          <td align="center" class="hidden-xs">{{ $auction->id }}</td>
          <td>{{ $event>name }}</td>
          <td>{{ $event->description }}</td>
          <td align="center">
          <div>
            <a href="{!! route('event_index', ['id' => $event->id ]) !!}" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success"><em class="fa fa-list-alt"></em></a>
           </div>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
<div class="text-right">
   {{ $events->render() }}
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share some code?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="text-right">
  <!-- Your pagination code here -->
</div>
```

Comment: This works for the allignment to the right, but how to decrease the distance between last row and the pagination. Have updated the original question with some code...

Comment: @wiwa1978 I don’t know your application. Look in the developer tools of your browser and find out what margins and paddings the element has.

Comment: Doing so tells me .pagination {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: 20px 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
} but this is in the bootstrap.css file which I'm getting from a CDN. Is there a way to override this margin value?

Comment: @wiwa1978 Yes. Create a stylesheet with your own overrides.

Comment: I have done that indeed and the margin is indeed decreased. However, even if I put the margin at 1px, it doesn't get closer than a certain minimum (which is more 1px). Any other ideas?